# find and loop items in array by id

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I have an array what contains multiple indexes like

```
$arr = array(
   1 => array('id' => 0,
              'container' => 1
        ),
   2 => array('id' => 1,
              'container' => 1
        ),
   3 => array('id' => 2,
              'container' => 2
        ),
   4 => array('id' => 3,
              'container' => 1
        )
);
```

How can I find and loop through all items where container is 1 and after that loop all items where container is 2 and so on..

Comment: What does `:` in your array definition do?

Comment: maybe you want to use `=>` instead of `:`

Comment: Ahh yes my mistake. Should be => working currenty on jQuery arrays so my bad. Thanks for the correction. But still need to find out the way to loop these items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. This one re-structures/groups the array by a given key - which is feasible if you iterate over all elements anyway.

```
<?php
$arr = array(
   1 => array('id' => 0,
              'container' => 1
        ),
   2 => array('id' => 1,
              'container' => 1
        ),
   3 => array('id' => 2,
              'container' => 2
        ),
   4 => array('id' => 3,
              'container' => 1
        )
);

$byContainer = groupBy($arr, 'container');
foreach($byContainer as $container=>$items) {
    echo $container, "\r\n";
    foreach($items as $e) {
        echo '  ', $e['id'], "\r\n";    
    }
}

function groupBy($arr, $key) {
    $result = array();
    foreach($arr as $e) {
        if ( !isset($result[ $e[$key] ]) ) {
            $result[ $e[$key] ] = array($e);
        }
        else {
            $result[ $e[$key] ][] = $e;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides from using the wrong array assignment `:`. Just change it to `=>`.

Then just use a foreach loop:

```
$containers = array(1, 2);
foreach($containers as $container) {
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        if($container == $value['container']) {
            echo "Container: $container : ";
            echo $value['id'] . '<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr = array(1 => array('id'=> 0, 'container'=> 1),
2 => array('id'=> 1, 'container'=> 1),
   3 => array('id'=> 2, 'container'=> 2),
   4 => array('id'=> 3, 'container'=> 1));
$temp = array();
foreach ($arr as $elem) {
 foreach ($elem as $k => $v) {
   if ($k == 'container') {
     $temp[$k][$v][] = $v;
   }
 }
}
print_r($temp);
?>
```

[Working Example](http://codepad.org/I3y0Fotp)